# How to add a quick and dirty, default/dummy icon to Xcode AppIcon asset class?

Tags: xcode

My app doesn't upload to App Store Connect, for TestFlight, because app store icon is missing (see below error).

What's the fastest way to populate the AppIcon asset class, to solve this?

I don't care what the icon is; this is only an internal test app.

> ITMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.company.KPdiag9May2022b'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't need to add an icon images to all the size in the asset catalogue. You just need to add one image and Apple's OS will take care of scaling for the rest. Not ideal for those who like to control every pixels in their apps but as you've said, it's for internal testing and you don't care if it even have an icon. Try to add an image for the largest size. It's the 1024x1024 @ 1x size. I don't believe the upload process will check if all the image size is populated in your AppIcon asset.

That's the fastest way I know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fastest solution:
3 clicks and a quick and 'clean' app store icon was ready to drag to the Xcode project -- took 1 minute.

App store icon generator
https://jpmallow.github.io/CopiCon/#/dashboard